# Issue running make on a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, msys2, postgresql-11

I'm running this on msys2 64 bit MINGW65 shell.

I ran

```
$source/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=$dist && make
```

and everything until the make runs properly. After getting the make issue and trying to tinker with the issue spot I keep running make for the same issue below.

Then when I run make on the folder.

it's running fine until it hits this part

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/builds/build/REL_11_8/src/backend/utils'
make -C storage/lmgr lwlocknames.h lwlocknames.c
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/builds/build/REL_11_8/src/backend/storage/lmgr'
'/usr/bin/perl' /c/builds/source/src/backend/storage/lmgr/generate-lwlocknames.pl 
/c/builds/source/src/backend/storage/lmgr/lwlocknames.txt
unable to parse lwlocknames.txt at /c/builds/source/src/backend/storage/lmgr/generate- 
lwlocknames.pl line 36, <$lwlocknames> line 8.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:33: lwlocknames.h] Error 255
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/builds/build/REL_11_8/src/backend/storage/lmgr'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:137: storage/lmgr/lwlocknames.h] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/builds/build/REL_11_8/src/backend'
make: *** [src/Makefile.global:372: submake-generated-headers] Error 2
```

In the generate-lwlocknames.pl

there is the following line that it's obviously triggering it.
But I don't know why it's triggering it or how to fix it.

I need to compile this build in order to be able to get the dll files for an extension for windows machine that is running postgres.

```
while (<$lwlocknames>)
{
    chomp;

    # Skip comments
    next if /^#/;
    next if /^\s*$/;

    die "unable to parse lwlocknames.txt"
      unless /^(\w+)\s+(\d+)$/;

    (my $lockname, my $lockidx) = ($1, $2);

    die "lwlocknames.txt not in order"   if $lockidx < $lastlockidx;
    die "lwlocknames.txt has duplicates" if $lockidx == $lastlockidx;

    while ($lastlockidx < $lockidx - 1)
    {
        ++$lastlockidx;
        printf $c "%s   \"<unassigned:%d>\"", $continue, $lastlockidx;
        $continue = ",\n";
    }
    printf $c "%s   \"%s\"", $continue, $lockname;
    $lastlockidx = $lockidx;
    $continue    = ",\n";

    print $h "#define $lockname (&MainLWLockArray[$lockidx].lock)\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After rerunning it a few more times it finished successfully. No changes were made to the files or methodology.

Comment: If the problem is not reproducible, it's probably best to just delete the question.

Comment: Maybe. But I also think it might be worth leaving it up as an experience for someone else that if they used the same tool and a similar thing happens. That the answer might just be to run it a few times. Cause I know I felt like I was reaching the edge of insanity sitting there running it multiple times. Cause it didn't happen once. It happened as my answer states. Multiple times with no difference. And eventually just worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are building with the Perl that comes with MinGW.

However, the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-windows-full.html#id-1.6.5.8.8) is pretty clear on that point:

> The following additional products are required to build PostgreSQL. Use the `config.pl` file to specify which directories the libraries are available in.
>
> [...]
>
> `ActiveState Perl`
>
> ActiveState Perl is required to run the build generation scripts. MinGW or Cygwin Perl will not work. It must also be present in the PATH. Binaries can be downloaded from https://www.activestate.com (Note: version 5.8.3 or later is required, the free Standard Distribution is sufficient).

Comment: I don't feel like that's related. Cause as my own answer says. Changing nothing it eventually just successfully built a fully working postgres.

Comment: Perhaps it is not related, but perhaps it is.

Comment: Well I say I don't think it is. Because I wasn't running Mingw. I was running the mingw that comes with msys2 which are different. But its a possibility. But also using that mingw64 shell with msys2 it ended up running with no changes. So if using mingw with perl doesn't work then it shouldn't be related